# QFT: 2d massless fermion propagator in coordinate space. Where am I wrong?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

I am trying to compute the fermion massless propagator in two dimension:
$i \int \frac{d^2k}{(2 \pi)^2} e^{ik \cdot x} \frac{k^0 \gamma^0 + k_1 \gamma^1}{k^2 + i \eta} = \frac{i}{(2 \pi^2)} \int dk^1 e^{ik^1x^1} \int dk^0 e^{-ik^0x^0} \frac{k^0 \gamma^0 - k^1 \gamma^1}{(k^0)^2 - (k^1)^2 + i \eta} = \frac{i}{(2 \pi^2)} \int dk^1 e^{ik^1x^1} (2 \pi i) e^{-i(k^1-i \eta)x^0} \frac{(k^1-i\eta)\gamma^0 - k^1\gamma^1}{2k^1-i \eta} = - \frac{1}{4\pi} (\gamma^0- \gamma^1) \int dk^1 e^{k^1(x^1-x^0) - \eta x^0} = -\frac{1}{4 \pi}(\gamma^0 - \gamma^1) \delta(x^0 - x^1).$

Where I put $\eta = 0$ where it is possible and I supposed that $x^0 > 0$.
The correct result, reported by Peskin-Schoreder is:
$- \frac{i}{2 \pi} \frac{\gamma^\mu x_{\mu}}{x^2}.$

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that "two dimensions" means 1+1 dimensions (in other words, two total dimensions, one spacelike and one timelike)? Is it possible that it means 1+2 dimensions (in other words, two spatial dimensions)?

Comment: I mean 1+1 dimensions

Comment: Is that also what Peskin and Schroeder mean, when they give their answer?

Comment: yes, pages 651-652 etc

Comment: Do you have take in accountancy that there are two poles ( in third step)?

Comment: Yes but I supposed that $x^0>0$ and so I closed the integration path from below, computing the residue at the pole at $k^0 = k_1 - i \eta$

Answer (score 3):

From the $+i\eta$ in the denominator, I'm assuming you're using the $(1,-1)$ signature but then I'm not sure why you wrote $ik\cdot x=-ik^0x^0+ik^1x^1$. More importantly, your second mistake is in the claim of a pole at $k_1-i\eta$. The poles for the $k^0$ integration are at $\pm(|k^1|-i\eta)$, i.e. they involve the magnitude $|k^1|$, not the variable $k^1$ directly.

Besides, it is rather messy to work with several gamma matrices in the integral. A cleaner approach is to push them to the side by writing:
$$
i\int \frac{d^2k}{(2\pi)^2}\frac{\gamma^\mu k_\mu}{k^2+i\eta}e^{ikx}=-i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu \int \frac{d^2k}{(2\pi)^2}\frac{i}{k^2+i\eta}e^{ikx}
$$
Now you can leave the $-i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu$ factor alone and work with the integral:
$$
G(x)= \int \frac{d^2k}{(2\pi)^2}\frac{i}{k^2+i\eta}e^{ikx}
$$
You may recognize this as the propagator of a massless scalar. There are already several answers on this site concerning the evaluation of this integral. See, for example, [here.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/490445/2-dimensional-massless-scalar-field-propagator-in-position-space)

The idea is still the same, depending on the sign of $x^0$ we can choose to close the contour either in the upper or lower plane. But it may be easier to do a Wick rotation and do the integration in Euclidean space. The result is, with the $i\eta$ prescription for $\ln(r)$ omitted :
$$
G(r)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln(r)
$$
Here $r=\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{x_0^2-x_1^2}$. The result for your original integral is:
\begin{align}
-i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu \frac{1}{2\pi}\ln(r)&=-\frac{i}{2\pi} \gamma^\mu \frac{1}{r}\partial_\mu \sqrt{x_\mu x^\mu} \\
&= -\frac{i}{2\pi} \frac{\gamma^\mu x_\mu}{x^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very clear! I am interested in the evaluation of $G(x)$. Do you know if there is any method of computation that avoid Bessel functions?